# MySQL architecture

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys

I am new to relational database architecture creation. I am creating a very basic one where I have two data tables.

```
CREATLE TABLE Authors (
idAuthors INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Birthplace VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (idAuthors));


CREATLE TABLE Shops(
idShops NOT NULL auto_increment,
Name_shop VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Name_authors VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Location VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (idShops));
```

My question is if you should have a foreign key in each table or an intermediate table that would be:

```
CREATLE TABLE intermediate(
PRIMARY KEY (idShops),
PRIMARY KEY (idAuthors));
```

Is this correct?

Thank you!

Comment: It only depends on what you want. If it is a many to many relationship, you can't accomplish it any other way.

Comment: *Is this correct?* No. The table cannot have 2 PKs and cannot have no columns.

Comment: I have in the authors table a different author for each row but in the shops table an author may appear several times. @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: And how should the intermediate table be? @Akina

Comment: Don't start thinking about tables and rows yet. A shop may have zero, one or more authors, right? How many shops can the author belong to?

Comment: You don't give a specification for your design/code to meet/model/implement/record, so we don't know what you "should" have. Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS Time to follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design & querying. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.) Ask a specific question where stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
CREATE TABLE Authors (
    idAuthors INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
    NameAuthor VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unknown',
    BirthPlace VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'not defined',
    PRIMARY KEY (idAuthors) 
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE Shops(
    idShops INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
    NameShop VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL 'unspecified',
    Location VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL 'not specified',
    PRIMARY KEY (idShops) 
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE Authors_Shops (
    idAuthors INT NOT NULL,
    idShops INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idAuthors, idShops),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Authors FOREIGN KEY (idAuthors) REFERENCES Authors (idAuthors),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Shops FOREIGN KEY (idShops) REFERENCES Shops (idShops) 
);
```